# Bottom view scrolls with recyclerview in viewpager with tablayout and Caordinatelayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I am using coardinate layout with recyclerview in viewpager and tablayout. I have a view for banner which i want to show over the recyclerview at the bottom. This bottom view is only visible if i scroll up the recyclerview list and hides when i scrollback down.I want this view to be visible all the time over recyclerview. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.[image: ente[![enter image description here]r image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g1lB.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g1lB.png)

Here is my xml code

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/deal_display_bg"
tools:context="com.safar.spicedeals_activities.DealsActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<View
    android:id="@+id/topview_deal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/spice_laddooblue"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/no_deals_available"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/no_deals_available"
    android:textColor="@color/spice_laddooblue"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayoutDeals"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bannerView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topview_deal"
    android:padding="2dp">

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarDeals"
            style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible" />
       </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout> -->
      </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_PriceTotal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_with_border_square"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_totalPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/total_price"
        android:textColor="@color/spice_laddooblue"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_totalPriceResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView_totalPrice"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_totalPrice"
        android:textColor="@color/spice_laddooblue"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_processDeal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_totalPrice"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/spice_laddooblue"
        android:text="@string/proceed_tag"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bannerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/curved_white_with_blue_border"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bannerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Banner"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bannerImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bannerClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cross_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you have to fix height of RecyclerView or gave padding from bottom to RecyclerView.

Comment: i already tried giving padding...but i did not worked..

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me! add this attribute for your android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
```

The `app:layout_scrollFlags` attribute of the Toolbar indicates to the view how to respond. It has the following possible values.

1. **scroll** : 
   This flag is generally set for all views that need to
   scroll off-screen. Views that don’t use this flag remain static
   allowing the other scrollable views to slide behind it.
2. **enterAlways** :
   This flag ensures that any downward scroll will cause the view to
   become visible, enabling the quick return pattern.
3. **enterAlwaysCollapsed** : 
   An additional flag for ‘enterAlways’ which
   modifies the returning view to only initially scroll back to it’s
   collapsed height.
4. **exitUntilCollapsed** : 
   This flag causes the view to
   be scrolled until it is collapsed (its minHeight is reached) before
   exiting
5. **snap** : Upon a scroll ending, if the view is only partially
   visible then it will be snapped and scrolled to it’s closest edge.
   Hence this avoids mid-animation states of a view

More details can be found [here](http://www.journaldev.com/12858/android-tablayout-appbarlayout).